# Escape tagname in XSL

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to render the following HTML code using xslt:

```
<foo:bar href="[MYURL]"/>
```

I created the following template:

```
<xsl:template name="displaySomeLink">
    <xsl:param name="url"/>
    <foo:bar href="{$url}"></foo:bar>
</xsl:template>
```

Which I'm planning to call like:

```
<xsl:call-template name="displaySomeLink">
    <xsl:with-param name="url" select="[MYURLSELECTIONLOGICS]"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

However, my xslt parser indicates justly that the foo prefix is not defined, and as the foo prefix doesn't signify anything at xslt level, I don't want to register it. Is there any way I can escape a character in a tagname?

(Of course I can easily do some other workaround, like concatenating a string which will output the same.)

Comment: I recommend defining it because that would be a way to really make clear that you mean exactly that namespace prefix and nothing else. Whats wrong with defining it?

Comment: If you _"don't want to register it"_, then there is no solution: XSLT stylesheet must be a well formed XML document.

Comment: @Chris: I think it would be even clearer when I escaped the tagname, when I'd register I could be meaning that I'd actually refer to an existing namespace, en when you would read my document you would have to check out whether that namespace exists, right?

Comment: @Alejandro :You're right, "_don't want to register it_" sounds a bit pushy, I meant "_I think it would be better not to register it_"

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation and complete solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define the `foo` namespace prefix in the XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:foo="http://foo.foo/foo"
                ...>
```

or

```
<xsl:template name="whatever" xmlns:foo="http://foo.foo/foo">
  ...
```

or

```
<xsl:template name="whatever">
   ...
   <foo:bar xmlns:foo="http://foo.foo/foo" />
   ...
```

You are correct in that the `foo` namespace prefix and its namespace have no meaning in XSLT, but neither have the default namespace "" or any other namespace except for the `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform` namespace (usually represented by the `xsl` prefix).

The XSLT processor will just spew out elements with whatever namespace they are defined in.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Furthermore I added the 'foo' prefix to the ignorelist: 'exclude-result-prefixes="foo"'

Comment: Well, in that case, shouldn't `<xsl:stylesheet xslns="http://foo.foo/foo" ...>` and `<bar href="..."/>` also do the job?

Comment: No, as I want the foo-part to be rendered as well.

Answer (score 1):

**An XSLT stylesheet must be a well-formed XML document**.

The error that you get is not XSLT-specific at all -- it is an XML parsing error.

The only way to make the XSLT stylesheet a well-formed XML document (preserving the name `foo:bar`) is to define some namespace with the prefix `foo` bound to it -- at a location that is visible (in scope) from the place of the `foo:bar` element.

**One way to do this is to define the namespace on the top element** (the `xsl:stylesheet` element):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:foo="my:foo" exclude-result-prefixes="foo">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<!-- more code here -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Also, do note the use of the `exclude-result-prefixes="foo"` attribute**. This specifies that the namespace nodes associated with any prefix in the list it contains (in this case just `foo`), will not be copied by the XSLT processor on any literal-result element.

Comment: @Dimitre: Shouldn't be `exclude-result-prefixes`?

Comment: @Alejandro: Good catch. Sometimes I don't look well at what the XSlelerator intellisense offers me.

Comment: @Dimitre: I know! And `exclude-result-prefixes` doesn't popup in the precense of other namespaces declaration... Off topic: Do you know if someone is maintaining that proyect?

Comment: @Alejandro: I know this person. He lost any interest in this project when he stopped selling it. I could spend some time on such a project if there is a good text-editor toolkit available.

Comment: @Dimitre, thanks for the answer and explanation, but I guess the answre has already been provided by @ndim (and I added the 'exclude-result-prefixes' myself)

Comment: @Robert-Sirre: My main contribution is for you to understand that your question has nothing to do with XSLT, as the error is produced by the XML parser long before any XSLT compilation and processing happens. Also, the accepted answer doesn't at all mention the necessity of specifying the `exclude-result-prefixes` attribute and thus the produced result is not at all what you want...

Comment: Thanks again. I understand your explanation, in fact it's the entire reason that I asked for escaping the character, which would be an XML escape. Now I think of it, would xml-encoding work?